# Equality in javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, oop

If I have this code:

```
var foo1 = new Foo();
var foo2 = new Foo();
```

and I want to do this:

```
function updateFoo1 (foo) 
{
   if (foo === foo1) //If foo is foo1
   {
       //code for processing
       return true;
   }
   else //Foo must be foo2 or another instance of foo not foo1
     return false;
}
```

Will this work as expected to make sure whether the function argument `foo` is the same as `foo1` and not `foo2` or any other instance of the `foo` class? If not, what should I do to get the result I want?

Comment: If you're testing that they're the same instance, then yes it works. Didn't it work when you tried it?

Comment: Well, have you tried it?

Comment: I don't know why people upvote questions like this. A 12k user should know to do basic research and testing before asking such a question.

Comment: @amnotiam If you don't want to answer a question, then don't. Simple. The question I asked is perfectly within the rules of this site to ask, and asking a question here always gives better results than googling something. Simply ignore questions that you don't like rather than trolling them.

Comment: Please review the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section, specifically under the **Do your homework** heading. You should know how the site works after asking over 460 questions. I mean seriously. Posting some code and basically asking someone else to test its result is poor.

Comment: @amnotiam "not every question on Stack Overflow gets answered. To improve your chances, here are some tips". **tips** aren't the same things as **rules**.

Comment: I didn't ask anyone to test it, what I asked was, will this code work and if not, what can I do to get the result I want. I got some reasons for why it works and if it didn't work, I would've gotten more info on that than by googling for it.

Comment: If you google for an answer there's no guarantee that you'll find what you're looking for or how good the answer that you find will be. Its simply more productive to ask your questions here when you have a real job and projects that need to be completed by a deadline.

Comment: Sad. Just really, really sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Foo(){}
var foo1 = new Foo();
var foo2 = new Foo();
console.log(foo1===foo2); // always false
```

Object comparison is being done by object's reference so `foo1` returns a different reference and `foo2` returns another reference. In your case

```
function updateFoo1(foo) 
{
    if (foo === foo1)
    {
        //code for processing
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
updateFoo1(foo1) // first if condition will work and will return true
updateFoo1(foo2) // else condition will work and will return false
```

[**See yourself here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/YW9Nc/1/)